# Why gimp 2.8 slow on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gimp

I am running ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on 4-core cpu and what i am facing is that when i open a .psd file or a heavy .xcf/.psd file my gimp sends me a "force quit" message. I am using gimp for professional image editing so please tell me what i should do.
Thanks

screenshot1-usage 2.2gb of memory by gimp
screenshot2-the time i closed gimp-4th core 90% and drops to 15%

[image: screenshot1-usage 2.2gb of memory by gimp]

[image: the time i closed gimp-4th core 90% and drops to 15%]

Comment: Try it from xfce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks simply like you're running out of memory… **:(**

Once SWAP gets heavily used, the response time of your computer goes up a 1000-fold.

Try this: Open the file, go make coffee (not just take, but fully make) and come back after 10 minutes or so.

If the file opens, but everything is *really* slow (like a click-and-drag takes a full minute), just buy more RAM…